# Android socket connection loses after app being idle for some time

Tags: android, sockets, connection

My application listens to a socket. The application is connected to the socket using the following method.

```
public void connect() {
    this.connectionStatus = CONNECT_STATUS_CONNECTING;
    Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, userId + " : Connecting to Server");
    if (mThread != null && mThread.isAlive()) {
        return;
    }
    mThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, userId + " : Thread Action Started");
                String secret = createSecret();

                int port = (mURI.getPort() != -1) ? mURI.getPort() : (mURI.getScheme().equals("wss") ? 443 : 80);

                String path = TextUtils.isEmpty(mURI.getPath()) ? "/" : mURI.getPath();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mURI.getQuery())) {
                    path += "?" + mURI.getQuery();
                }
                String originScheme = mURI.getScheme().equals("wss") ? "https" : "http";
                URI origin = new URI(originScheme, "//" + mURI.getHost(), null);

                SocketFactory factory = mURI.getScheme().equals("wss") ? getSSLSocketFactory() : SocketFactory.getDefault();
                mSocket = factory.createSocket(mURI.getHost(), port);


                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(mSocket.getOutputStream());
                out.print("GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                out.print("Upgrade: websocket\r\n");
                out.print("Connection: Upgrade\r\n");
                out.print("Host: " + mURI.getHost() + "\r\n");
                out.print("Origin: " + origin.toString() + "\r\n");
                out.print("Sec-WebSocket-Key: " + secret + "\r\n");
                out.print("Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n");
                if (mExtraHeaders != null) {
                    for (NameValuePair pair : mExtraHeaders) {
                        out.print(String.format("%s: %s\r\n", pair.getName(), pair.getValue()));
                    }
                }
                out.print("\r\n");
                out.flush();

                HybiParser.HappyDataInputStream stream = new HybiParser.HappyDataInputStream(mSocket.getInputStream());

                // Read HTTP response status line.
                StatusLine statusLine = parseStatusLine(readLine(stream));
                if (statusLine == null) {
                    Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "Received no reply from server.");
                    throw new HttpException("Received no reply from server.");
                } else if (statusLine.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_SWITCHING_PROTOCOLS) {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(statusLine.getStatusCode(), statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }

                // Read HTTP response headers.
                String line;
                boolean validated = false;

                while (!TextUtils.isEmpty(line = readLine(stream))) {
                    Header header = parseHeader(line);
                    if (header.getName().equals("Sec-WebSocket-Accept")) {
                        String expected = createSecretValidation(secret);
                        String actual = header.getValue().trim();

                        if (!expected.equals(actual)) {
                            Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "Bad Sec-WebSocket-Accept header value.");
                            throw new HttpException("Bad Sec-WebSocket-Accept header value.");
                        }
                        validated = true;
                    }
                }

                if (!validated) {
                    Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "No Sec-WebSocket-Accept header.");
                    throw new HttpException("No Sec-WebSocket-Accept header.");
                }
                onConnect();
                Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, userId + " : Thread should be connected by now");
                // Now decode websocket frames.
                mParser.start(stream);
            } catch (EOFException ex) {
                Log.d(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "WebSocket EOF!", ex);
                onDisconnect(0, "EOF");
            } catch (SSLException ex) {
                // Connection reset by peer
                Log.d(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, "Websocket SSL error!", ex);
                onDisconnect(0, "SSL");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                onError(ex);
            }
        }
    });
    Log.v(AppConstants.DEBUG_TAG, userId + " : Thread about to be started");
    mThread.start();
}
```

Here the problem is when I leave the application for 15 or more idle, the connection automatically closes and app becomes unusable.What is the reason behind it and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, it is the server that closes the idle connection. Send [Ping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.2) (or [Pong](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.3)) periodically to keep the connection.

BTW, I guess your code is based on a certain open-source WebSocket library. If so, note that it is not of commercial quality. It does not perform even the [closing handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7.1.2) on `disconnect()`.

Comment: Similiar problem as in the question here... Is it possible that one can still send data with the WebSocket, but not receive it with such an "idle connection"? That's what may cause my issue at the moment.